# How to pass an array with query objects from http client in Angular 8

Tags: angular, http, mongoose, httpclient, url-parameters

I am working on angular 8 as a front end framework and mongoDb as a backend with nodeJS.
I want to send an http get request form angular which would produce a conditional query for mongoose such as

```
$or:[
   {name:jhon},
   {name:sam}
]
```

I have tried

```
let param = new HttpParams();
for (let name of names){
  param = param.append('$or',JSON.stringify({'name':name}));
}
```

But this produces

```
$or:[
   '{name:jhon}',
   '{name:sam}'
]
```

And generates an error
*$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects*

So is there a way to pass objects in an array with http parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The object you are trying to send seems like a JSON object.You can always send a json object as a payload in a post request. I don't will send this kind of data as params. It will be more easy to process to you.

Comment: I am trying to make a get request actually. Had it been a post request, you are right in that I should send it as a payload. I am trying to fetch a name that is jhon or Sam or any other from mongodb.